# Refreshing a div when the window is resized

Tags: jquery, html, overflow

I have a problem with a div or to be precise with the overflow. I have the following code:

```
<div class="overlay" id="Overlay_1">
    <div id="OverlayContent">
        Some content.
    </div>
</div>
```

The class "overlay" is just to have the actual overlay and a close button, all made in jQuery with some CSS and jQuery Tools. The problem is, when I have some really long content and I resize the window of the browser, the div with the content do not "refresh" and then the content flows over the div. When I maximize the window again everything is fine again.
What I want to try now is some kind of reloading the div when the size of the browser window is changing, so it reloads all the sizes of the div and the overflow, so it will fit again. I tried the following jQuery code.

```
$(window).resize(function() {
    $('#OverlayContent').load();
});
```

Nevertheless nothing happens. I also tried with changing the width of the overlays to see if the code works at all. There I have seen that it doesn't work for the "OverlayContent" but for "Overlay_1".
I think the problem is the div inside of the div. So is there any solution how I simply can refresh a div when the size of the window is changed. I thought jQuery here was a good starting point, but now I am not sure.

Comment: Reading docs is _good starting point_. For example, to learn what `.load()` actually does.

Comment: We definitely need more of your jQuery code to give you an accurate answer. A less accurate answer would be: recalculate and reapply the div’s dimension.

Comment: This sounds like more of a CSS issue. Can you post the CSS?

Comment: @Spode: This is *not* a css issue. It's a jquery/javascript issue.

Comment: How can you be so certain without seeing it? Text flowing outside of a block sounds like an issue with CSS?

Comment: @Spode yes, I think that most probably it can be fixed with CSS.

Comment: @Spode: I can say this as **.load** does something completely different from what OP is asking/suggesting it is doing.

Comment: The documentation states: "Load data from the server and place the returned HTML into the matched element.". That doesn't suggest it affects the element you are injecting content into. 

If you can give us a point of reference for why you are so certain, then please do - otherwise you are simply being stubborn.

Comment: At the moment this question leaves a lot to user interpretation. Please post a sample code illustrating the problem. Why are you using `.load()`? Are the contents of your overlay dynamically fetched from the server using AJAX? I am voting to close this question until sufficient info/example is added.

Comment: Thanks for the answers. I put my code at JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/gep0s6ct/
You can see what happens by resizing the Result frame. If there is enough space the text fits in the overlay, when it is to small it start being the overlay

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to reload the `div` infact. Just try as below so that content fits to the div when `window` is `resized`

Add below style to your `div`

```
    div {
    width: 500px;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    font-size: 2vw;
}
```

For Demo **[click here](https://css-tricks.com/viewport-sized-typography/)** and **[Fiddle Demo here](https://jsfiddle.net/ohd0f43m/3/)**

**EDIT**

Check this **[UPDATED DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/gep0s6ct/2/)**

You had a property in your `.overlay` class where you have set `max-height:80%`. That's where it was making problem!!! I've set it to `100%`

```
.overlay {
min-width:400px;
max-width:75%;
width:auto;
min-height:200px;
max-height:100%; //this was 80%
height:auto;
margin-top:20px;
background:rgb(250,250,250);
background:rgba(250,250,250,0.9);
border: 1px solid #000000;
display:none;
z-index:10000;
-webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
-moz-box-sizing: border-box;
box-sizing: border-box;
border-radius:5px;
-webkit-border-radius:5px;
-moz-border-radius:5px;
box-shadow: 2px 4px 7px 2px #bbb;
-webkit-box-shadow: 7px 7px 5px #bbb;
-moz-box-shadow: 7px 7px 5px #bbb;
}
```

Comment: Tbh I don't see how this address' the OP's issue?

Comment: @jbutler483.. He has mentioned **The problem is, when I have some really long content and I resize the window of the browser, the div with the content do not "refresh" and then the content flows over the div** !! I just said why to refresh the `div` if only fitting the content is the ultimate goal.. :)

Comment: I am not trying to put this down, but the only reason this 'works' isn't because of the vw units - it's because you have set the height to auto? (set it to a fixed value and you'll see why this won't work for **this** particular issue). If height was auto then text wouldn't overflow anyway?

Comment: @jbutler483.. without seeing his `css` how can you say that this will not work for **this** particular problem? how do you know what he has set for height? Most of the times its the `css` which comes into picture for this kind of problem and why use javascript when it can be solved with css??

Comment: From the description *'so it reloads all the sizes of the div and the overflow, so it will fit again'* - suggesting there is an overflow set. Setting a font-size has nothing to do with overflow.

Comment: Ok. I agree that we can assume like that about the overflow. But here the problem is all about `window resize` and ultimately fitting the contents inside the div without overflowing and even though you remove `vw` units and mention in `px` units this works.

Comment: Thanks for the answers. I put my code at JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/gep0s6ct/
You can see what happens by resizing the Result frame. If there is enough space the text fits in the overlay, when it is to small it start being the overlay

Comment: @stuchaet.. I don't find any problem!! It's fine right??

Comment: No, it's not.
I made two screenshots. Here with the maximized browser window: abload.de/img/maximizeduhse7.png And for small windows it looks like this: abload.de/img/minimizeddvsj0.png

Comment: Oh my god, that was to simple. :D I thought this would only apply to the overlay itself and won't do anything with the content. Just changed it to 100% and it works perfectly fine! Thank you so much!!!

Comment: Anytime. Happy coding. :)

Answer (score 0):

## Case 1:

*I have overflow:hidden or overflow:auto or overflow scroll set, but the text keeps going out of the div for a short time (slow refresh on resize*)

---

> So is there any solution how I simply can refresh a div when the size
> of the window is changed

You could use the likes of:

```
$("#OverlayContent").html($("#OverlayContent").html());
```

in order to redraw the content on resize. This works as it 'refreshes' the content rather than [loading](https://api.jquery.com/load/) the content (which is a different method from what you believe it to be).

---

## Case 2:

*I am trying to create a responsive layout, and I've set a height and width on my div. I don't know what overflow i should be setting.*

If, however, you are looking for a way for the 'extra text' to scroll (instead of overflow), I wish to ensure you have used a declaration such as:

```
overflow:auto;
```

in which will add a scroll bar if the text is too long.

[more information on overflow CSS property](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visufx.html)

---

## Case 3:

*A want to width to adjust to the size of the screen, and have height alter to contain the text. I do not want to have scroll bars.*

In order for this, you could set a width to be either a 'variable value' - by using % or view width units, for example. this means the box will adjust according to the screen (without setting an overflow):

```
width:80%;
height:auto; /*this will ensure text 'fits' the container*/
min-height:100px; /*optional. Ensures box is always at least 100px tall.*/
```

This would allow you to alter the textbox according to screen size.

Comment: Content should be drawn automatically on resize as it repaints. How is this meant to help? Replacing itself with itself?

Comment: @Spode: It recalculates the size of div (that is, if OP has overflow:hidden and still seeing text overflow). Since the likes of chrome only recalculates every-so-often, this causes 'text to appear outside' of the div even *with* overflow hidden for a period of time. 'Replacing its contents with itself' forces this redraw.

Comment: Chrome will recalculate when you resize the window. This feels hacky. If it is actually triggering something in Jquery, then there is likely a way of triggering the resize.

Comment: @Spode: Chrome has a habit of 'lagging' when a lot of content is present. Always has had a few bugs with its overflow property.

Comment: Window resizing is a heavy process - most likely that lag is intentional. However, that's not the issue being presented - it's not happening *at all*.

Comment: Thanks for the answers. I put my code at JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/gep0s6ct/
You can see what happens by resizing the Result frame. If there is enough space the text fits in the overlay, when it is to small it start being the overlay

Comment: @stuchaet: I'm not sure If I can replicate the issue here? What browser and version are you currently using to replicate this?

Comment: I am using the recent version of Firefox, but it also happens in Chrome.

Comment: I made two screenshots.
Here with the maximized browser window: http://abload.de/img/maximizeduhse7.png
And for small windows it looks like this: http://abload.de/img/minimizeddvsj0.png

Comment: @stuchaet: Please try to implement Case 1 from my answer. Seems like you're facing a rendering issue. I can't reproduce, but could you try [this](http://jsfiddle.net/jbutler483/gep0s6ct/1/) for me?

Comment: Already tried this, but the errors is still there. Even tried it on other computers and with different browsers.

Comment: @stuchaet: I would suggest trying an updated version of jquery. However, this seems to be an issue with the actual plugin you are using.

Comment: This cannot be the problem because I am already using the last version of jQuery. Otherwise I would work in JSFiddle because it uses the last version of jQuery.